How to implement AD B2C authentication on an ASP Net Core application that has Razor pages and web API in a single application
I am trying to secure the application using AD B2C, The application has Razor Pages and WebAPI. The razor pages .cs file has requests to the webapi using httpClient. I have gone through the sample B2C app and have a clear idea of how to secure the web app and webapi individually and how to make request using bearer tokens.
But I haven't found anything that describes the security implementation when Application (Razor page + Web API) has both the frontend and backend service.
Please let me know if you have any idea/approach to implement security for the above scenario.
I have checked with just adding the service AddWebAppAuthentication() and this service is able to authenticate the Webapp and WebAPI but on making requests to the API - response was a HTML content.(Probably B2C Login Page).
Then I also tried exposing the api and consuming the api in the single app registration and then generating an accesstoken using ITokenAcquisition (and was able to generate the accesstoken and passes in the request as the bearer token) But the response was still A HTML content.

I try to use B2C with this "on behalf of" flow but get a 401 response. Checked the details it said invalid "audience". So I added following configuration to the api project and it works.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         //.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
          {
              builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

              // Additional options
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  ValidAudience = "https://myb2cxxx.onmicrosoft.com/{api clientId}}"
              };
          }, options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); }
         );

To clarify all the steps I have done:
1.Use webapi with Azure auth template project. Register webapi app in B2C, expose api - create scope "access_as_user".
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myb2cxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }

2.Use Razor pages with Azure auth template project. Register Razor app in B2C, add api permission "https://myb2ctxxx.onmicrosoft.com/{api clientId}/access_as_user" and grant admin consent. Add secret, redirect uri.
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myb2cxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "https://myb2cxxx.onmicrosoft.com/{api clientId}/access_as_user"
  }

To call the api
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://myb2cxxx.onmicrosoft.com/{api clientid}/access_as_user" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7299/weatherforecast");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ViewData["ApiResponse"] = apiResponse;
            }

Test result

